# r - import data, columns are character spaces

Tags: r, import

I have a file containing data which I need to import into a dataframe but the setup of the file is quite terrible.

the file I am trying to import is a list of 344 characters (32 colums, 445k rows). Each column is specific range of character spaces.

Column 1 is character spaces 1:2

Column 2 is character spaces 3:6

Column 3 is character spaces 7:20
and so forth.

**data example:**

```
the.data <- list("32154The street", "12546The clouds", "23236The jungle")
```

**what I need it to look like**

```
col1   col2   col3
 32    154    The street
 12    546    The Clouds
 23    236    The jungle
```

What I've tried:

```
substr(the.data, 1,2)
substr(the.data, 3,6)
substr(the.data, 7,20)
```

and bind it together

I would like to find a better solution

I also tried to insert commas at the right character spaces, export it as a csv and re-import (or use textConnection) but ran into problems there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readr` in the `tidyverse` can read fixed width data.

```
library('tidyverse')

read_fwf(paste(the.data, collapse='\n'), fwf_widths(c(2,3,15)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      X1    X2         X3
#>   <int> <int>      <chr>
#> 1    32   154 The street
#> 2    12   546 The clouds
#> 3    23   236 The jungle
```

Comment: That is nice.  I was going to suggest `read.fwf(ff, widths = c(3, 2, 15))`

Comment: Great solution, I can read it straight from the file. Only problem I'm currently having is encoding

Answer (score 1):

One option is to insert delimiter in the `unlist`ed data using `sub` and then read with `read.csv/read.table`

```
read.csv(text=sub("^(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(.*)", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
    unlist(the.data)), header = FALSE, 
       col.names = paste0("col", 1:3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#   col1 col2       col3
#1   32  154 The street
#2   12  546 The clouds
#3   23  236 The jungle
```

---

Or we can use `separate` based on position

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
unlist(the.data) %>%
      as_tibble %>%
      separate(value, into = paste0("col", 1:3), sep= c(3, 5))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   col1  col2  col3      
#* <chr> <chr> <chr>     
#1 321   54    The street
#2 125   46    The clouds
#3 232   36    The jungle
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
> library(stringr)
> data.frame(col1=str_sub(the.data,1,2),col2=str_sub(the.data,3,5),col3=str_sub(the.data,6,-1))
  col1 col2       col3
1   32  154 The street
2   12  546 The clouds
3   23  236 The jungle
```